# Nose piercing in Hinduism

Tags: belief, tradition, women, customs

I have read that Hindus usually pierce nose on the left side. Why is it so?

Is there any bad omen related to right side nose piercing?

Comment: I don't think there is anything like that..both sides are pierced..even some pierce the middle portion too..astrologically some consider piercing of nose as a remedy for malefic Budha(mercury)..